# Adding CSS styles to a form_tag in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css

I have a Rails app where I am using custom stylesheets that have no effect on the `<form>` tags generated by the Rails `form_tag` helper. Can someone point me to some code or an example that shows how to add CSS styles to a `form_tag`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<% form_tag {:controller => 'my_controller', :action => 'my_action'}, :id => 'my_id' do %>
```

in .css file

```
#my_id {
 /* your style */
}
```

Comment: or use :class => 'my_class' on all forms

Answer (score 0):

With the [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) helper, the first argument you pass is used exclusively by the [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for) helper to determine what URL to submit the form to. Hash-style named arguments are treated as a single argument (a hash) by Ruby, so if you pass a set of options as your first argument (e.g. `form_tag(controller: 'my_controller', action: 'show')`), any additional options you include (like `:method` or `:class`) will be treated as options to `url_for` instead of to `form_for`, which isn't what you want.

To fix this, you can explicitly pass a hash as the first argument to `form_tag`, and put your other options (such as the class attribute, which is probably what you'll want to use for styling) outside of that hash, like so:

```
<% form_tag {controller: 'my_controller', action: 'show'}, class: 'main-form' do %>
  <!-- Form content here -->
<% end %>
```

After that, you can use css to style your form as you would with any other element:

```
.main-form {
  // Style rules here
}
```

For more information on the options `form_for` accepts, see the docs for [`form_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) and [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/RoutingUrlFor.html#method-i-url_for).

Answer (score -3):

Few ways you can do this:

```
form {
  color: red;
}
```

This will grab ALL forms and style them.

```
#id {
  color: red;
}
```

This will grab the forms that match the ID and style them.

```
.class {
  color: red;
}
```

This will grab the forms that match the class and style them.

Comment: He ask how to add class or id to form_for, not how to style it in css.